# bindings : count number of true booleanproperty in an observable list

Tags: data-binding, javafx

i have this TableView of tasks that has a column of checkboxes. i've managed to extract the column values using stream().map(). i want to count the true values in that list.

```
ObservableList<BooleanProperty> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList(tasksTable.getItems().stream().map(t -> t.completedProperty()).collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

and another integer property

```
SimpleIntegerProperty count = new SimpleIntegerProperty(0);
```

i want this count value to be updated to the total number of true values in the list. how can i do this. i tried binding it like this

```
IntegerBinding count = Bindings.createIntegerBinding(() -> {
    return (int)list.stream().filter(done -> done.get()).count();
}, list);
```

and added a listener to monitor for changes.

```
count.addListener((o, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    System.out.println('value changed ' + newValue);
});
```

but its not working... nothing gets printed when i click on any checkbox...

Answer (score 2):

You binding doesn't update, if the `BooleanProperty`s in the list change, only when the list itself is modified. You can specify conditions that trigger update changes using the [correct `observableArrayList` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/FXCollections.html#observableArrayList-javafx.util.Callback-).

#### Example

```
// update triggers every time a BooleanProperty in the list is changed
ObservableList<BooleanProperty> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList((Callback<BooleanProperty, Observable[]>) e -> new Observable[] {e});

list.add(new SimpleBooleanProperty(false));
IntegerBinding trueNum = Bindings.createIntegerBinding(() -> (int) list.stream().map(BooleanProperty::get).filter(b -> b).count(), list);

trueNum.addListener((a, b, c) -> {
    System.out.println(c);
});

System.out.println(trueNum.get());
list.get(0).set(true);
list.add(new SimpleBooleanProperty(false));
list.add(new SimpleBooleanProperty(true));
list.get(2).set(false);
```

The output is

```
0
1
2
1
```

---

This has the drawback of reevaluating the whole list every time one of the properties changes or the list is modified. You can do this more efficiently, if you use a `ListChangeListener` and register change listeners to all of the properties contained in the list:

```
ObservableList<BooleanProperty> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

...

SimpleIntegerProperty count = new SimpleIntegerProperty();

ChangeListener<Boolean> changeListener = (observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
    // increment or decrement if value was changed to true or false respecively
    count.set(count.get()+ (newValue ? 1 : -1));
};

// get initial value and register change listeners to elements of list
int currentCount = 0;
for (BooleanProperty p : list) {
    if (p.get()) {
        currentCount++;
    }
    p.addListener(changeListener);
}
count.set(currentCount);

list.addListener((ListChangeListener.Change<? extends BooleanProperty> c) -> {
    int modification = 0;
    while (c.next()) {
        // remove listeners from all properties removed in change
        // and calculate update of value
        for (BooleanProperty p : c.getRemoved()) {
            p.removeListener(changeListener);
            if (p.getValue()) {
                modification--;
            }
        }
        // add listeners from all properties added in change
        // and calculate update of value
        for (BooleanProperty p : c.getAddedSubList()) {
            p.addListener(changeListener);
            if (p.getValue()) {
                modification++;
            }
        }
    }
    // update count
    count.set(count.get()+modification);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your lambda is called only once. You specify dependency `list` but uses `tasksTable.getItems()` In lambda-extractor you should use only values you specify as dependencies.

Also take a look at [EasyBind](https://github.com/TomasMikula/EasyBind) library.